# Максимальное время работы скрипта

Tags: php, timeout

Мой скрипт обрабатывает очень большой объем данных. На небольших объемах все работает отлично. Когда объем данных увеличиваю, через пару секунд страница перестаёт загружаться и остается просто белый экран.
Вопрос: как заставить скрипт доделать работу до конца? `set_time_limit` не помог. Или нужно что-то другое?

Comment: Оптимизация кода?

Comment: Запуск из консоли.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, чем вам

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Так я паршу огромные объемы данных, и скрипт у меня прекрасно выполняется по несколько часов.